# Show message while javascript is running

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I know that most probably such question has been requested several times but I have a need to show a popup or message or whatelse when a javascript function is triggered and hide it at the end.

See this simple js [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/23ZFY/1/)

That's the HTML code:

```
<div id='message'>Default message</div>
<input type='button' onclick='Run();' value='start'>
```

the div 'message' has to contain a simple text like "running" or "please wait" or ...

That's the JS function that took (delay) 3 seconds:

```
function Run() {
    var delay = 3000;   //-- 3 seconds
    $( '#message' ).text('Please wait ' + delay + ' seconds...');
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    while (true) {
        current = new Date().getTime();
        if ( (start + delay) < current) {
            break;
        }
    }
    $( '#message' ).text('Done');
}
```

The expected behaviour is that the '#message' div contains "Please wait 3 seconds..." before to enter in the loop and "Done" string only at the end.

But that's not.
Can anyone explain me (most probably "again") why or suggest a link where to find an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The JS event loop is too busy running `while (true) {}` to handle a DOM repaint.

Use `setInterval`, `setTimeout`, or `requestAnimationFrame` to trigger the next test of the time instead of a loop.

```
function Run() {
    var delay = 3000;   //-- 3 seconds
    $( '#message' ).text('Please wait ' + delay + ' seconds...');
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    setTimeout(whenDelayIsOver, 50);

    function whenDelayIsOver() {
        if ( (start + delay) < current) {
            $( '#message' ).text('Done');
        } else {
            setTimeout(whenDelayIsOver, 50);
        }
    }
}
```

… or just use `setTimeout` in the first place.

```
function Run() {
    var delay = 3000;   //-- 3 seconds
    $( '#message' ).text('Please wait ' + delay + ' seconds...');
    setTimeout(whenDelayIsOver, delay);

    function whenDelayIsOver() {
        $( '#message' ).text('Done');
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, that's a little bit more clear. So the reason is due to the fact that [ while true ] statement is too heavy to be handled with right priority?

but what happens in case of the [ while (true) ] statement is replaced with a piece of javascript that (for example) need to change the border color of ~1000 different div availale on the page and that would take some seconds? In such case how can I show to the users a message like 'Please wait' during processing even not knowing in advance how long does it take?

Comment: It isn't so much a case of priority as "Waiting until the function has finished running". If you want to update that many elements, then do them in batches.

Answer (score 2):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/23ZFY/11/

```
function Run() {
    var secs = 3;
    $('#message').text('Please wait '+ secs +' seconds...');
    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        if (secs == 1) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            $('#message').text('Done');
            return;
        }
        secs--;
        $('#message').text('Please wait ' + secs + ' seconds...');
    }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The browser's display is only updated when the function completely finishes running.
You can run the second lot of code asynchronously by using setTimeout.

```
function Run() {

    $('#message').text('Please wait 3 seconds...');
    setTimeout(

    function () {
        var start = new Date().getTime();
        while (true) {

            current = new Date().getTime();
            if ((start + 3000) < current) {
                break;
            }
        }
        $('#message').text('Done');
    },0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a very tight loop (while(true)...) which doesn't allow the UI to update at all. What you can do instead is this:

```
function Run() {
    var delay = 3000; //-- 3 seconds    
    $('#message').text('Please wait ' + (delay/1000) + ' seconds...');
    setTimeout(function () {
          $('#message').text('Done');       
    }, delay);
}
```

Basically, set the "wait message" initially and use the `setTimeout` function to update the message again after 3 seconds.

[Updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/23ZFY/7/)

Comment: A countdown will look nicer :)