# Javasript function to change a HTML class of a <div>, render, then continue running the rest of the function code

Tags: javascript, html

I am learning programming HTML/CSS/Javascript. I created a webpage and a javascript code to get some information within an Access database then render it to user. It is a big table sometimes.
I just want to update a  class and an innerHTML at the beginning and in the end of the code, in order to show to the user: "Wait, page is loading"... and after the code runs, change the  class and innerHTML to nothing ("") then the message to user would disappear.

I did the code, but when my function runs, it is not rendering the changes to class and innerHTML until the functions is finished...

JUST FOR INFORMATION: At this point, the HTML is already rendered. The Javascript will act from a button click on the page.

My HTML - The classes and innerHTML I want to update with Javascript code.

```
    <section>
        <div id="RunningCode" class="">
            <span id="RunningCode1" class=""></span>
        </div>  
    </section>
```

My JAVASCRIPT CODE in the beginning of the function. (This is what I want to render/update before the code continue

```
var YellowCard = document.getElementById("RunningCode");
YellowCard.className = "mensagemCodeRunning";

var YellowCard1 = document.getElementById("RunningCode1");
YellowCard1.className = "mensagemCodeRunningText";
YellowCard1.innerHTML = "Loading. Please Wait..."
```

Then My JAVASCRIPT CODE in the end of the function:

```
YellowCard1.className = "";
YellowCard1.innerHTML = ""

YellowCard.className = "";
```

FULL JAVASCRIPT CODE:

```
function getSpecificSupplier() 
{ 

var YellowCard = document.getElementById("RunningCode");
YellowCard.className = "mensagemCodeRunning";

var YellowCard1 = document.getElementById("RunningCode1");
YellowCard1.className = "mensagemCodeRunningText";
YellowCard1.innerHTML = "Loading. Please Wait..."

var Carrier_Name = Carrier_NameHTML.value;

var cn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection"); 

var strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = MySource;
var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset"); 


var SQL = "select * from ...

cn.Open(strConn); 
rs.Open(SQL, cn); 

var Linhas_da_Tabela = document.getElementById("Apagando");

while(Linhas_da_Tabela.firstChild) {
    Linhas_da_Tabela.removeChild(Linhas_da_Tabela.firstChild);
}

while (!rs.eof) {

    var table = document.getElementById("mytable");
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    var cell0 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(3);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(4);
    var cell5 = row.insertCell(5);
    var cell6 = row.insertCell(6);
    var cell7 = row.insertCell(7);
    var cell8 = row.insertCell(8);


    cell0.innerHTML = rs1
    cell1.innerHTML = rs2
    cell2.innerHTML = rs3
    cell3.innerHTML = rs4

    var WholeDate = new Date(rs("Arrival Time"));
    var dd = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', { minimumIntegerDigits: 2 }).format(WholeDate.getDate());
    var mm = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', { minimumIntegerDigits: 2 }).format(WholeDate.getMonth()+1);
    var yyyy = WholeDate.getFullYear();
    var hh = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', { minimumIntegerDigits: 2 }).format(WholeDate.getHours());
    var min = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', { minimumIntegerDigits: 2 }).format(WholeDate.getMinutes());

    cell4.innerHTML = "" + mm + "-" + dd + "-" + yyyy + " " + hh + ":" + min + "h";

    var WholeDate = new Date(rs("Gate IN"));
    var dd = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', { minimumIntegerDigits: 2 }).format(WholeDate.getDate());
    var mm = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', { minimumIntegerDigits: 2 }).format(WholeDate.getMonth()+1);
    var yyyy = WholeDate.getFullYear();
    var hh = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', { minimumIntegerDigits: 2 }).format(WholeDate.getHours());
    var min = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', { minimumIntegerDigits: 2 }).format(WholeDate.getMinutes());

    cell5.innerHTML = "" + mm + "-" + dd + "-" + yyyy + " " + hh + ":" + min + "h";

    var WholeDate = new Date(rs("Dock IN"));
    var dd = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', { minimumIntegerDigits: 2 }).format(WholeDate.getDate());
    var mm = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', { minimumIntegerDigits: 2 }).format(WholeDate.getMonth()+1);
    var yyyy = WholeDate.getFullYear();
    var hh = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', { minimumIntegerDigits: 2 }).format(WholeDate.getHours());
    var min = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', { minimumIntegerDigits: 2 }).format(WholeDate.getMinutes());

    cell6.innerHTML = "" + mm + "-" + dd + "-" + yyyy + " " + hh + ":" + min + "h";

    var WholeDate = new Date(rs("Dock OUT"));
    var dd = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', { minimumIntegerDigits: 2 }).format(WholeDate.getDate());
    var mm = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', { minimumIntegerDigits: 2 }).format(WholeDate.getMonth()+1);
    var yyyy = WholeDate.getFullYear();
    var hh = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', { minimumIntegerDigits: 2 }).format(WholeDate.getHours());
    var min = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', { minimumIntegerDigits: 2 }).format(WholeDate.getMinutes());

    cell7.innerHTML = "" + mm + "-" + dd + "-" + yyyy + " " + hh + ":" + min + "h";

    var WholeDate = new Date(rs("Gate OUT"));
    var dd = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', { minimumIntegerDigits: 2 }).format(WholeDate.getDate());
    var mm = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', { minimumIntegerDigits: 2 }).format(WholeDate.getMonth()+1);
    var yyyy = WholeDate.getFullYear();
    var hh = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', { minimumIntegerDigits: 2 }).format(WholeDate.getHours());
    var min = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', { minimumIntegerDigits: 2 }).format(WholeDate.getMinutes());

    cell8.innerHTML = "" + mm + "-" + dd + "-" + yyyy + " " + hh + ":" + min + "h";

rs.MoveNext
}

rs.Close(); 
cn.Close(); 

YellowCard1.className = "";
YellowCard1.innerHTML = ""

YellowCard.className = "";


}
```

Comment: can you show the whole function?

Comment: `var strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = MySource;` is an unterminated string and will throw syntax errors.

Comment: Hi @RobbieMilejczak, I updated as requested. I just deleted the source from the connection string. Just to let you know, this part of the code is working fine. The only issue is to update the screen with the msg "Loading. Please Wait..." while JavaScript is reading the database...

Comment: Sorry @esqew, I cannot pass the connection string here because of security reasons. It is a connection to an MS Access Database...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show message while javascript is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23698512/show-message-while-javascript-is-running)

Comment: Hey @Jeff, I am really new on JavaScript... Can you please send me an example adapting in my JS code? I already saw that post before, tried it but no success. Maybe I did something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this post:  [Show message while javascript is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23698512/show-message-while-javascript-is-running)

Repaint happens after a function executes, if you enclose the javascript code you are executing in a setTimeout(), you'll be able to repaint the DOM before the code starts executing.

Pull this part out into a separate function

```
var YellowCard = document.getElementById("RunningCode");
YellowCard.className = "mensagemCodeRunning";

var YellowCard1 = document.getElementById("RunningCode1");
YellowCard1.className = "mensagemCodeRunningText";
YellowCard1.innerHTML = "Loading. Please Wait..."
```

like this:

```
function run(){

    var YellowCard = document.getElementById("RunningCode");
    YellowCard.className = "mensagemCodeRunning";

    var YellowCard1 = document.getElementById("RunningCode1");
    YellowCard1.className = "mensagemCodeRunningText";
    YellowCard1.innerHTML = "Loading. Please Wait...";

    setTimeout(getSpecificSupplier(), 0);

    function getSpecificSupplier() { 
        // need to redefine these variables
        var YellowCard = document.getElementById("RunningCode");
        var YellowCard1 = document.getElementById("RunningCode1");


        var Carrier_Name = Carrier_NameHTML.value;

        var cn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection"); 

        ...

        YellowCard1.className = "";
        YellowCard1.innerHTML = ""

        YellowCard.className = "";


    }

}
```

Comment: Hey Thanks Jeff! Working very good!!! I had no success at before because I was using the 'setTimeout' in the same function! Thanks so much for your support.